# Update DB when exists golang

Tags: go-gorm

I am using Go Gorm for my app. The backend DB is MySQL. I want to use Gorm to update the DB only if the record exists. I have tried `save` and `updates` but they don't work as I expect. How to archive it?

Comment: Please provide more details and what exactly have you tried. Kindly read through the [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I think my question is simple. I just want to update a record only if it exists using go-gorm, otherwise return an error. I have tried using `save` and `update` queries but they don't work.

Comment: You can use Assign for that.
http://jinzhu.me/gorm/crud.html#query
This is the complete Description
https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/issues/1307

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the given code, maybe it help you to identify the issue. Jst run it in your local it work for me.

```
func init() {
    var err error
    // db, err = gorm.Open("sqlite3", "test.db")
    // db, err = gorm.Open("postgres", "user=gorm dbname=gorm sslmode=disable")
    db, err = gorm.Open("mysql", "root:@/test?charset=utf8&parseTime=True")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    db.LogMode(true)
    db.AutoMigrate(&User{})
    var user = User{Name: "jinzhu", Age: 10}
    db.Save(&user)
}

func FindUser(id int64) *User {
    var u User
    db.First(&u, id)
    return &u
}

func main() {
    user := FindUser(1)
    user.Age = 20
    db.Save(user)

    db.Model(user).Update("name", "hello")
    db.Model(user).Updates(User{Name: "hello again"})
}
```

If you want to update only one cloumn then you can use:

```
db.Model(user).UpdateColumn(User{Name: "Hello"})
```